# Records listing incorrect results based on table data Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have table which have fields named: `transaction_date`, `amount`.

Basically, I am calculating earnings and expenses based on that `amount` column which have number of records in that.

Now, issue is that I am unable to populate my records based on year and month. And their calculations as well.

Suppose, I have year 2015 and database have records of jan, feb, march and april only for 2015. So, I want to populate these records only with all these months.

My query is working but its not calculating proper results.

This is what I am trying:

```
SELECT
    SUM(amount) AS total_amount,
    SUM(IF(amount < 0, amount, 0)) AS expenses,
    SUM(IF(amount > 0, amount, 0)) AS earning,
    transaction_date
FROM
    `tbl_finanace`
WHERE
    transaction_date LIKE '%2015%' 
AND user_id = 15
GROUP BY
    MONTH (transaction_date)
ORDER BY
    transaction_date
```

And here is the output of this query:

```
total_amount expenses       earning     transaction_date 
-4120.25    -36289.00       32168.75    2015-01-02
-591.30     -8504.55        7913.25     2015-02-01
-3270.60    -12312.85       9042.25     2015-03-01
-51.90      -211.90         160.00      2015-04-01
```

My results should be something like this:

```
total_amount expenses       earning     transaction_date 
-114.80     -1051.80        937.00      2015-01-02
25.40       -174.60         200.00      2015-02-01
34.90       -165.10         200.00      2015-03-01
-51.90      -211.90         160.00      2015-04-01
```

If I use below for single date for multiple entries of that date, it shows correct results for that date only But I need to have these results based on year and records of months present for that year with correct calculations.

Query:

```
SELECT
    SUM(amount) AS total_amount,
    SUM(IF(amount < 0, amount, 0)) AS expenses,
    SUM(IF(amount > 0, amount, 0)) AS earning,
    transaction_date
FROM
    `tbl_finanace`
WHERE
    transaction_date LIKE '%2015-01-02%'
AND user_id = 15
GROUP BY
    YEAR (transaction_date)
ORDER BY
    transaction_date
```

Results:

```
-114.80   -1051.80  937.00  2015-01-02
```

Here are some of mine records for march and april month for demo purpose only. These are original records.

Table Structure with sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_finanace` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `finance_type` varchar(225) NOT NULL,
  `finance_date_time` varchar(225) NOT NULL,
  `transaction_date` date NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `contract` varchar(225) NOT NULL,
  `strike` varchar(225) NOT NULL,
  `expiry_time` varchar(225) NOT NULL,
  `profit` varchar(225) NOT NULL,
  `contact_amount` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `finance_date_time` (`finance_date_time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3129 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `financDB`.`tbl_finanace` (`id`, `finance_type`, `finance_date_time`, `transaction_date`, `description`, `amount`, `user_id`, `contract`, `strike`, `expiry_time`, `profit`, `contact_amount`) VALUES ('4957', 'Sell', 'Sell--2015-03-25--10:09:17', '2015-03-25', '2 EUR/USD >1.0970 (12PM) @ 46', '-108.00', '15', '', '', '', '', '0');
INSERT INTO `financDB`.`tbl_finanace` (`id`, `finance_type`, `finance_date_time`, `transaction_date`, `description`, `amount`, `user_id`, `contract`, `strike`, `expiry_time`, `profit`, `contact_amount`) VALUES ('4958', 'Fee Payment', 'Fee Payment--2015-03-25--10:09:17', '2015-03-25', '2 EUR/USD >1.0970 (12PM) @ 46', '-1.80', '15', '', '', '', '', '0');
INSERT INTO `financDB`.`tbl_finanace` (`id`, `finance_type`, `finance_date_time`, `transaction_date`, `description`, `amount`, `user_id`, `contract`, `strike`, `expiry_time`, `profit`, `contact_amount`) VALUES ('4959', 'Settlement Payout', 'Settlement Payout--2015-03-25--12:00:06', '2015-03-25', '2 SHORT EUR/USD >1.0970 (12PM) @ 46', '0.00', '15', '', '', '', '', '0');
INSERT INTO `financDB`.`tbl_finanace` (`id`, `finance_type`, `finance_date_time`, `transaction_date`, `description`, `amount`, `user_id`, `contract`, `strike`, `expiry_time`, `profit`, `contact_amount`) VALUES ('4960', 'Buy', 'Buy--2015-03-31--08:29:35', '2015-03-31', '2 EUR/JPY >129.00 (3PM) @ 59.25', '-118.50', '15', '', '', '', '', '0');
INSERT INTO `financDB`.`tbl_finanace` (`id`, `finance_type`, `finance_date_time`, `transaction_date`, `description`, `amount`, `user_id`, `contract`, `strike`, `expiry_time`, `profit`, `contact_amount`) VALUES ('4961', 'Fee Payment', 'Fee Payment--2015-03-31--08:29:35', '2015-03-31', '2 EUR/JPY >129.00 (3PM) @ 59.25', '-1.80', '15', '', '', '', '', '0');
INSERT INTO `financDB`.`tbl_finanace` (`id`, `finance_type`, `finance_date_time`, `transaction_date`, `description`, `amount`, `user_id`, `contract`, `strike`, `expiry_time`, `profit`, `contact_amount`) VALUES ('4962', 'Sell', 'Sell--2015-03-31--10:10:06', '2015-03-31', '2 USD/CAD >1.2720 (3PM) @ 46', '-108.00', '15', '', '', '', '', '0');
INSERT INTO `financDB`.`tbl_finanace` (`id`, `finance_type`, `finance_date_time`, `transaction_date`, `description`, `amount`, `user_id`, `contract`, `strike`, `expiry_time`, `profit`, `contact_amount`) VALUES ('4963', 'Fee Payment', 'Fee Payment--2015-03-31--10:10:06', '2015-03-31', '2 USD/CAD >1.2720 (3PM) @ 46', '-1.80', '15', '', '', '', '', '0');
INSERT INTO `financDB`.`tbl_finanace` (`id`, `finance_type`, `finance_date_time`, `transaction_date`, `description`, `amount`, `user_id`, `contract`, `strike`, `expiry_time`, `profit`, `contact_amount`) VALUES ('4964', 'Buy to Close', 'Buy to Close--2015-03-31--10:58:04', '2015-03-31', '2 USD/CAD >1.2720 (3PM) @ 12', '176.00', '15', '', '', '', '', '0');
INSERT INTO `financDB`.`tbl_finanace` (`id`, `finance_type`, `finance_date_time`, `transaction_date`, `description`, `amount`, `user_id`, `contract`, `strike`, `expiry_time`, `profit`, `contact_amount`) VALUES ('4965', 'Fee Payment', 'Fee Payment--2015-03-31--10:58:04', '2015-03-31', '2 USD/CAD >1.2720 (3PM) @ 12', '-1.80', '15', '', '', '', '', '0');
INSERT INTO `financDB`.`tbl_finanace` (`id`, `finance_type`, `finance_date_time`, `transaction_date`, `description`, `amount`, `user_id`, `contract`, `strike`, `expiry_time`, `profit`, `contact_amount`) VALUES ('4966', 'Sell to Close', 'Sell to Close--2015-03-31--13:47:00', '2015-03-31', '2 EUR/JPY >129.00 (3PM) @ 6', '12.00', '15', '', '', '', '', '0');
INSERT INTO `financDB`.`tbl_finanace` (`id`, `finance_type`, `finance_date_time`, `transaction_date`, `description`, `amount`, `user_id`, `contract`, `strike`, `expiry_time`, `profit`, `contact_amount`) VALUES ('4967', 'Fee Payment', 'Fee Payment--2015-03-31--13:47:00', '2015-03-31', '2 EUR/JPY >129.00 (3PM) @ 6', '-1.80', '15', '', '', '', '', '0');
INSERT INTO `financDB`.`tbl_finanace` (`id`, `finance_type`, `finance_date_time`, `transaction_date`, `description`, `amount`, `user_id`, `contract`, `strike`, `expiry_time`, `profit`, `contact_amount`) VALUES ('4968', 'Sell', 'Sell--2015-04-01--09:33:50', '2015-04-01', '2 EUR/JPY >129.20 (3PM) @ 41', '-118.00', '15', '', '', '', '', '0');
INSERT INTO `financDB`.`tbl_finanace` (`id`, `finance_type`, `finance_date_time`, `transaction_date`, `description`, `amount`, `user_id`, `contract`, `strike`, `expiry_time`, `profit`, `contact_amount`) VALUES ('4969', 'Fee Payment', 'Fee Payment--2015-04-01--09:33:50', '2015-04-01', '2 EUR/JPY >129.20 (3PM) @ 41', '-1.80', '15', '', '', '', '', '0');
INSERT INTO `financDB`.`tbl_finanace` (`id`, `finance_type`, `finance_date_time`, `transaction_date`, `description`, `amount`, `user_id`, `contract`, `strike`, `expiry_time`, `profit`, `contact_amount`) VALUES ('4970', 'Buy to Close', 'Buy to Close--2015-04-01--09:43:41', '2015-04-01', '1 EUR/JPY >129.20 (3PM) @ 20', '80.00', '15', '', '', '', '', '0');
INSERT INTO `financDB`.`tbl_finanace` (`id`, `finance_type`, `finance_date_time`, `transaction_date`, `description`, `amount`, `user_id`, `contract`, `strike`, `expiry_time`, `profit`, `contact_amount`) VALUES ('4971', 'Fee Payment', 'Fee Payment--2015-04-01--09:43:41', '2015-04-01', '1 EUR/JPY >129.20 (3PM) @ 20', '-0.90', '15', '', '', '', '', '0');
INSERT INTO `financDB`.`tbl_finanace` (`id`, `finance_type`, `finance_date_time`, `transaction_date`, `description`, `amount`, `user_id`, `contract`, `strike`, `expiry_time`, `profit`, `contact_amount`) VALUES ('4972', 'Buy to Close', 'Buy to Close--2015-04-01--09:45:13', '2015-04-01', '1 EUR/JPY >129.20 (3PM) @ 20', '80.00', '15', '', '', '', '', '0');
INSERT INTO `financDB`.`tbl_finanace` (`id`, `finance_type`, `finance_date_time`, `transaction_date`, `description`, `amount`, `user_id`, `contract`, `strike`, `expiry_time`, `profit`, `contact_amount`) VALUES ('4973', 'Fee Payment', 'Fee Payment--2015-04-01--09:45:13', '2015-04-01', '1 EUR/JPY >129.20 (3PM) @ 20', '-0.90', '15', '', '', '', '', '0');
INSERT INTO `financDB`.`tbl_finanace` (`id`, `finance_type`, `finance_date_time`, `transaction_date`, `description`, `amount`, `user_id`, `contract`, `strike`, `expiry_time`, `profit`, `contact_amount`) VALUES ('4974', 'Buy', 'Buy--2015-04-01--22:28:01', '2015-04-01', '2 AUD/USD >.7600 (11AM) @ 44.25', '-88.50', '15', '', '', '', '', '0');
INSERT INTO `financDB`.`tbl_finanace` (`id`, `finance_type`, `finance_date_time`, `transaction_date`, `description`, `amount`, `user_id`, `contract`, `strike`, `expiry_time`, `profit`, `contact_amount`) VALUES ('4975', 'Fee Payment', 'Fee Payment--2015-04-01--22:28:01', '2015-04-01', '2 AUD/USD >.7600 (11AM) @ 44.25', '-1.80', '15', '', '', '', '', '0');
```

Comment: Post some records which you want to process.

Comment: I have added insert statements here. [http://en.m.textsave.org/bw1b](http://en.m.textsave.org/bw1b) I have added in question as well. Please see. @Ravinder

Comment: As there isn't anything obvious -- and your data are far too long to be examined naked eye -- could you consider providing an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) demo ?

Comment: Here is the sqlfilddle: [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4a591/2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4a591/2) @SylvainLeroux

Comment: @user3228030 Thank you. Does the sqlfiddle demo exhibits the same odd behavior ?

Comment: No, sqlfiddle demo does not exhibits the same odd behavior. I have checked only for march records. @SylvainLeroux

Comment: What are you expecting the results of the SQL Fiddle to be? Which fields are not correct?

Comment: My sqlfiddle records shows correct results but on site they are not working. They are working only for 4th record in my results (from both working and not working results) @GarethD

Comment: your query seems to be fine except the like in the where clause, but that should not be the reason of the problem. are you sure that you need to sum all the amount values? (maybe there are some that you don't want to, based on contract or sg, this is one thing that I can imagine). also, providing sample data for april is not the best for finding the problem, because this is the only month when your query actually produces good results.

Comment: @lp_ You are 100% saying right it is showing correct results only for april month.:) second, Yes, I am sure to sum all the amount values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want results by month, then you need to `group by` the month.  Also, you should not use `like` with date/time columns.  I would expect something like this:

```
SELECT month(transaction_date),
       SUM(amount) AS total_amount,
       SUM(IF(amount < 0, amount, 0)) AS expenses,
       SUM(IF(amount > 0, amount, 0)) AS earning   
FROM `tbl_finanace`
WHERE transaction_date >= '2015-01-01' AND user_id = 15
GROUP BY MONTH(transaction_date)
ORDER BY MONTH(transaction_date);
```

This seems to work on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4a591/13).

Comment: How to make `transaction_date >= '2015-01-01'` statement more dynamic? I mean for year 2016, or 2017?

Comment: @user3228030: For 2016 I would use `transaction_date >= '2016-01-01'` and for 2017, er, give me some time to figure this out ;-)

Comment: Sorry, still same old results. I am not expecting output results from this query as well.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I got you Sir by saying this. :) but I am still expecting the incorrect results. But when I select date by date as I have showed an example when it works, it seems working but only for that date/month.

Answer (score 0):

On first glance:

- transaction_date is a date. So why do you use string operations on it (`LIKE '%2015-01-02%'`)? You shouldn't.
- You are using a MySQL feature here. You group by month or year, but show transaction_date . The shown transaction_date is hence a random date in that month or year. So in spite of having a line for 2015-01-02, the line actually shows values for the complete month 2015-01 or year 2015.

Hope this helps you finding the error.

Comment: So, what should be a query look like? I have changed my query as per your first point but still same results. @Thorsten

Comment: Tried your second point as well. It computes aggregate records of 2015 means no row by row records for each month in 2015. @Thorsten

Comment: I must admit, I don't understand. Is it working now or not? When selecting records of year 2015 and grouping by month, you get one record per month (of 2015) and the amounts for that month. Is that the case?

Comment: Sir its not working still. No its not that case. Let me explain you please. When I selects records of year 2015 and grouping by month it shows the results which I have stated in my problem results above in question. The calculations seems not working. Please review my query results and expected results.

Comment: I am pretty sure you are mistaken. It is highly unlikely for the values to be incorrect. I recommend you look at the expenses records for the first month and check the values: `SELECT * FROM tbl_finanace WHERE year(transaction_date) = 2015 AND month(transaction_date) = 1 AND amount < 0;`.

Comment: It am badly fed up as I am confused why its not working on site. :( Well, I have summed up all the records as per your query for expenses and results are: `-36289.00`

Comment: Which is the sum you get. So the query works fine. The sum is not -1051.80 which you expected to see for some reason, because the sum is -36289.00, as you can plainly see now. The query is correct, your expectation isn't :-)

Comment: Thank you very much @Thorsten. :) your conversation make more sense to me now. :)